# how to remove particular substring from string using id of li in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string

### 0=>zxz##5=>zxzx##5=>zxz##10=>zxz##1=>asdasd##12=>asdsad##10=>asdsad

where 0,5,10 are ids, text are values and ## is delimiter.

I have id and i want to remove id's value

This is my following code, Please check and suggest.

code1

```
function remove_feature(id)
{
    var feature_str  = $("#features_post").val();
    var feature_string = feature_str.replace(['id=feature_str'],'', 'gi');  
    window.jQuery("#features_post").val(feature_string); 
    window.jQuery("#"+id+"").remove();
      alert(feature_string);
    return true;
}
```

code2

```
 function remove_feature(id)
{
    var feature_str  = $("#features_post").val();
    var feature_string = feature_str.replace(id,'', 'gi');  
    window.jQuery("#features_post").val(feature_string); 
     window.jQuery("#"+id+"").remove();
    alert(feature_string);
        return true;
    }
```

I have tried both of code but not working

Comment: Show us an example of a desired output please. I've upvoted this because you've shown a good attempt yourself but you should be clear in what you want to happen.

Comment: if i pass id =5 then string should be like this
0=>zxz##5=>zxzx##10=>zxz##1=>asdasd##12=>asdsad##10=>asdsad

Comment: You're using the same ID (`5`) multiple times in your sample. Is that a mistake or purpose? If the latter, are you saying you want to remove the first item with that ID?

Comment: Sorry this is a spelling mistake.  i just copy and paste the string 5 and 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one with jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/h0qtxn7d/
Can also remove same multiple ids.

```js
var k = "0=>zxz##5=>zxzx##5=>zxz##10=>zxz##1=>asdasd##12=>asdsad##10=>asdsad";
var obj = k.split("##");
var removeItem = 5;

alert('Array before removing the element = ' + obj)
obj = jQuery.grep(obj, function(value) {
  return value.split('=>')[0] != removeItem;
});

alert('Array after removing the element = ' + obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Misread the question, sorry.

To replace each key => value pair within that string you could use regular expressions:

```
var string = "0=>zxz##5=>zxzx##5=>zxz##10=>zxz##1=>asdasd##12=>asdsad##10=>asdsad";

function remove_feature(id) {
  var x = new RegExp("" + id + "\=>[a-z0-9]+(##)?", "gi")

  return string.replace(x, "");
}
```

So, `remove_feature(5)` prints `"0=>zxz######10=>zxz##1=>asdasd##12=>asdsad##10=>asdsad"`.

---

If the id parameter is a key which exists in your provided string and the respective name should be returned you could make use of the JSON.parse function pretending to parse a url. Therefore you could replace the delimiters by `&`s and the `=>` by `=`s:

```
var string = "foo=>bar##john=>doe";

function remove_feature(id) {
  // id should be something left hand side the =>, like 0 or 1
  var _string = string.replace('##', '&').replace('=>', '='),
    obj = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(_string).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}'),
    _id = obj["" + id];

  $('#' + _id).remove();
}
```

Usage: `remove_feature("foo")` would remove an element with id `#bar`.

Comment: Its giving syntax error = SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at line 1 column 4 of the JSON data